# SQLSERVER 2008 executing a select statement repeatedly causes High CPU usage

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, loops

Is there any alternative from using a loop in my code to execute a select statement repeatedly to get value of live status column in my table?

It's a simple "Select status from dbo.mytable". But,I have no idea why this simple sql statement takes so much CPU when being executed on a loop.

Right now,the loop makes sqlserver use more than 50% of the CPU. Please advice any alternative or a way to solve this.

Thanks.

> Edit: Before someone says "why do you
>   need a loop?", "don't use a loop",etc,
>   let me explain that this is not my
>   requirement. It's from my
>   company.Thanks

Comment: there's no way of knowing without you posting the actual code and show us the execution plan for that code

Comment: Can't do no debuggin' without seeing them thar codes. And database schema. And info on indexes. Etc.

Comment: How often is the sql statement executed? Do you use a loop without any thread sleep ?

Comment: sounds like you might be missing a where clause.  how big is the table? what is the point of the loop?

Comment: Andrew Barber and others are correct here. Without seeing your query and the DDL on the table anything anybody says here is no better than if you had called a psychic hot line to get an answer. It could be a lack of a WHERE clause, poor indexing, or a computed column, or a combination of any of those or more that I have not mentioned.

Comment: You should probably look at SQL Server Query Notifications to be pushed notification when the data is updated rather than constantly polling.

Comment: Thanks for that martin...do you have any pointers to where I can find info to get that done? Can I get notification on my C# code when the table gets updated?

Comment: @Josh - Yes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated we need some code to properly debug but these are my thoughts...

How fast is this loop going? If it is quite literally

```
while (x == false) {
x = SQL STATEMENT
}
```

then yes, you will cause a massive amount of SQL load because the query will be running many thousands of times a second.

If on the other hand you are using a timer and looping every few seconds then such load is unusual unless:

- There are a large number of clients using the application so in effect there are multiple loops all hitting the server at the same time
- You are selecting a very large amount of data
- Your indexes aren't especially efficient
- You're not breaking out of previously completed loops causing unnecessary load

Finally you could perhaps look at building some caching into your DAL to reduce the number of queries actually making it to the SQL server. You can implement your own logic to do this or perhaps use something like this: http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.CacheAspect.ashx

Comment: Thank you...This is the kind of advice I need

Answer (score 2):

> why this simple sql statement takes
>   so much CPU

- Because it already is a loop (SELECT with no WHERE condition returns all the rows) and need not be called on a loop
- Perhaps because you have too many rows
- Maybe because no indexes on `status`

Having a **non-clustered index on `status`** can **hugely improve the performance.** *Reason is SQL Server would not need to touch the table at all.* But still does not make much sense to call it in a loop.

Comment: Thank you...This is the kind of advice I need

Answer (score 0):

How often does your loop call the statement?

There is a huge difference between

```
Foreach day 
  at noon: call query
```

and

```
Foreach millisecond
  call query
```